# React Native elements icons android - how to get rid of shadow appearing onpress?

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

When using react native elements icons, specifically with raised or the SocialIcon, on android after the click, there is always a weird shadow appearing for a second. How can I get rid of that? You can see it even on their own demo page and it only happens in android, not ios.

> https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/components/socialicon

Unfortunately, I couldnt find any answers anywhere. Thanks